# How to use Excel HYPERLINK function to link to an URL with query parameters?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

*This is observed under OSX 10.8.5 with Office 2011 (mac).

The hyperlink function seems not working with url with query parameters, why?

> HYPERLINK("http://mysite.com?foo=bar&x=y", "my link")

If I put above in Excel, the

> "x=y"

part gets dropped when clicking on it. My guess is that HYPERLINK function does not support query parameters. But somehow

> "foo=bar"

does not get dropped because it is after question mark.

Comment: Which version of Excel and how exactly are you adding the link?  Which browser are you using?  In Excel 2007 if I just Hyperlink some text in a cell the ampersand in the URL parameters stays intact, and it also stays intact if I use Insert Function/Hyperlink.

Comment: Yep, works on Excel 2007 (windows), not on Excel 2011 (mac).

Comment: Is this loading Safari and if so, which version?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on a mac in excel 2011, not sure that you don't have something else happening.

[image]